# SetTag() in a CalendarEvent results in an "Action not allowed" Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

When trying to set a tag for the first `CalendarEvent` in the "events" array I get an "Action not Allowed" error.  Other attributes of `CalendarEvent`, including `getStartTime()`, `getTag()`, `setLocation()`, etc. are perfectly functional.

I am the owner of this calendar event too, so I do not understand why I cannot tag the event.  I've tried on different events as well, including both those that I own and those I do not own, but none allow me to set a tag.

```
 function myFunction() {
   var myCal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
   var now = new Date();
   var events = myCal.getEvents(new Date(now.valueOf() - 14*24*3600*1000), new Date(now.valueOf() + 14*24*3600*1000))

  var temp = events[0];
  temp.setTag('key', 'pair')
}
```

Comment: After further investigation it appears I only get this issue with my main default calendar and not with other user created calendars.  My default calendar is a corporate managed Google account, so my issue may have something to do with this?

Comment: you are missing a ";" at the end of your `events` line. Have you corrected that in your original code?

Comment: Although, I tested your exact function thoroughly and just added the line `Logger.log(temp.getTag('key'));` at the end of the code and everything seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: The semicolon was not the issue.  I attempted to upload a snapshot but was unable to.

The code fails at  'setTag()' and so the tag is never set for me to check if it was set.  My problem seems to only be with my default corporate calendar, so I believe now this may have to do with some security setting.  The exact same code with a different calendar does not throw this error message.

Comment: @nsp13 did you ever find out how to fix that? I'm experiencing the same issue with my corporate calendar (and not a private account).

Answer (score 2):

I was running in to the same issue.

The root cause seems to be that you can only set a tag on a calendarApp event if you are the creator of the of the event. Right now, the calendar add-on I'm testing is using OAuth scopes that are within the context of my user. Maybe there's a way to user the context of say a workspace admin, but not sure, I'm new to using Google APIs.

To reproduce:

1. Create your own Google Calendar event.
2. Have someone else create a Google Calendar event and invite you to it.
3. Run `setTag('foo', 'bar')` on your event, it should (?) work
4. Run `setTag('foo', 'bar')` on the other person's event, it should (?) fail

I'm using Google Apps Script for a CalendarApp Add-on, and at least with that, I think you'll also need the following OAuth scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"`

Here's a quick example:

```js
run_tests();

function run_tests() {
  test_setTag('your_email@example.com', 'event-id-that-you-created');
  test_setTag('other_person@example.com', 'event-id-that-other-person-created');
}

function test_setTag(calendarId, eventId) {
  var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).getEventById(eventId);
  event.setTag('foo', 'bar');
}
```

**Edit - more complete answer:**

Updated understanding.

`CalendarApp` is a high-level abstraction over the low-level `Calendar` API. While easier to use, CalendarApp does not expose the full functionality of the low-level API.

Events within the Calendar API have `extendedProperties`, which are just optional metadata that users and apps can use to extend functionality. There are both `shared` and `private` properties within extendedProperties, and behave as follows:

- `shared` = a single value is shared between any users invited to the event. Invited users can read these values (with proper OAuth scope) but only the event creator may modify them.
- `private` = each user invited to an event can create and maintain their own, separate private properties. Other users cannot read or write these values.

The problem I experienced (and maybe you, too?) was that `CalendarApp` "tags" are an abstraction for `shared` extendedProperties...i.e. you cannot call `setTag` on an event where you are not the creator or owner.

By using the low-level Calendar API, I was able to successfully set **private** properties on an event I did not own but (as expected) trying to set a shared property failed (with a much clearer error code than `CalendarApp`, by the way).

```js
  const calendarId = 'your-calendar-id';
  const eventId = 'an-event-someone-else-made';

  var currentProperties = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId).extendedProperties || {};
  console.log('Properties before patch: ', JSON.stringify(currentProperties, null, 2));

  var schemaOfPatch = { 
    extendedProperties: {
      private: {
        foo: 'bar'
      } 
    }
  };
  Calendar.Events.patch(schemaOfPatch, calendarId, eventId);

  var patchedProperties = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId).extendedProperties || {};
  console.log(`Properties after patch: ${patchedProperties}`);

  // The null will remove the private property 'foo' 
  var schemaOfPatch = { 
    extendedProperties: {
      private: {
        foo: null
      } 
    }
  };
  Calendar.Events.patch(schemaOfPatch, calendarId, eventId);
```

Results of above:

[successful patch of private property to someone else's event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mqdI.png)

**If you change** `private` to `shared`, you will see this error:

[patch fails if made against shared property on event you do not own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Nva.png)